# Modify default text in subject+body in "Send e-mail" section of the "Add users" screen

Tags: 2007

I would like to modify the default text in **Subject** and **Personal message**, on the page:

```
http://(sharepoint)/_layouts/aclinv.aspx
```

Where do I change the text?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About three ways I can see this being done:

1. Make a copy of the aclinv.aspx page, name it something like aclinv_custom.aspx. In the aspx you copied modify the text properties of the txtEmailSubject and txtEmailBody controls : 1 Problem though, you would need to modify the Javascript in the page itself as this sets the subject value.
2. Make a copy of the page as above, except this time create a custom page class that inherits from Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.AclInv. Override the Page load event and set the properties programtically. Change the inherits tag in the copied page to point to the newly created class. You would still need to change the page javascript though.
3. Make a copy of the page as above, in the head of the aspx modify the javascript in the UpdateEmailSubject() javascript function to set the subject text field, you could also set the body text in the same way.

All these approaches would require that you update any setting page links that take the user to the original aclinv.aspx. You could do this using feature actions to remove the existing link and add in your custom link. This way you avoid modifying any of the OOTB files, and you can deploy the new page via a solution avoiding any issues with service pack updates etc that may modify the original page.

Hope this helps

Stuart

Comment: OK - thanks for the answer. Isn't there a resource file, or something like that where I can change it? The text isn't embedded into acliv.aspx.

Comment: No it isnt in a resource file. The subject is created dynamically in the page's assembly, it changes depending on what the user is being added to. The message is empty by default.